# Laravel route resource can't updated the value

Tags: php, laravel

Is one of my form and fetching value from database which are before inserted :

```
<form class="form-horizontal bordered-group" role="form" action="{{ route('invoice.update' , $invoice->id)}}" method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
          <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="GET">

  <div class="form-group clear"></div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-sm-4" >Subtotal: &nbsp;</label>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Tk.</div>
      <input name="subtotal" type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" value="{{ $invoice->subtotal}}" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-sm-4"><button type="button" id="total" class="btn btn-primary">Total</button></label>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Tk.</div>
      <input name="total" type="number" class="form-control" id="totalAmount" value="{{ $invoice->total}}" required>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer no-border clear">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

And Is one of my controller :

```
public function update($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
    $invoice->subtotal = $request['subtotal'];
    $invoice->total = $request['total'];
    $invoice->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Invoice Updtaed Successfully'] );
}
```

How i can solve my problem and updtae my database value ??

Comment: where does your $request comes from?

Answer (score 3):

Change code to:

```
<form class="form-horizontal bordered-group" role="form" action="{{ route('invoice.update' , $invoice->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="Put">
```

Method of you form is always `POST`. `_method` input element contains [HTTP verbs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) (Put, Delete etc).

Also, you should inject `Request` object to make it work:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Comment: Yes,,its working ,, thank you so much @Alexey Mezenin.

Comment: Doing $request['subtotal'] on a Request $request can't work and would result with: PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Request as array

Comment: @jakubwrona, you can access properties with `$request['subtotal']`, `$request->get('subtotal')` or `$request->subtotal`.

Comment: Ok, you are both right, I had no idea about it works this way. But I will stick to my get() ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to $request, but you are not passing this variable, so try:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
    $invoice->subtotal = $request->get('subtotal');
    $invoice->total = $request->get('total');
    $invoice->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Invoice Updtaed Successfully'] );
}
```

Or, create your own Request class with the right validation and ACL, and pass an instance of it to your update method.

Comment: @NazmulHossain: are you getting any error, are you sure the update() was called? could you share your rotes definitions?

Comment: thanks for your attention ,,now its solved @Jakub wrona.